# how to hide region when there is no date in region through dynamic action in apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5

How to hide region when there is no date in region through  dynamic action

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant "no data" rather than "no date"?

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic action would have to inspect the HTML of the region for evidence that no rows had been returned.  For example, when using the Universal Theme, a span with a class of "nodatafound" is rendered when a classic report returns no data.  So the presence of this span tells you that you need to hide the region.  If your region has a static ID of "myreport" then this dynamic action would work:

- Event: Page Load
- Client-side condition type: Javascript Expression
- Client-side condition Javascript Expression:

  `$('#myreport span.nodatafound').length > 0`
- True Action: Hide
- Selection Type: region
- Region: (the report region)